# Google Analytics local IP filter not working

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to filter out traffic from local IP address from my development machine. I have created a separate view in Admin panel for this. I have entered `/(localhost)|(^127\.)|(^192\.168\.)|(^10\.)|(^172\.1[6-9]\.)|(^172\.2[0-9]\.)|(^172\.3[0-1]\.)|(^::1$)|(^[fF][cCdD])/` in Admin Panel > View > Filters (as shown in image below).

[image]

I am doing something wrong here? Is my regex for Local IPs correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This regex should cover all the cases (but it exceeds 255 characters):

```
/(^192\.168\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)|(^172\.([1][6-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-1])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)|(^10\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)/gm
```

This should cover all the above cases but is more optimized:

```
/^(?:10|127|172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])|192\.168)\..*/
```

Comment: I am getting this error below input field: `Must be at most 255 characters`